# is this mentioned in scriptures that lord kridhna's son shamva ji sailed eastwards and reached japan and lived there?

Tags: scripture, vedas, vishnu, puranas, krishna

Some historians say that the Japanese people were a group of Indians following the story that the Shamva, the son of Lord Krishna sailed eastwards thousands of years ago from India to settle in the Land of the Rising Sun. India is the mother of all oriental civilisations. Samurais are the descendants of Krishna the God of justice, and Shamva ji was the origin of the Samurais.